# Show that $\hat{L}^2=\hat{r}^2\hat{p}^2 + i\hslash \hat{r} \cdot \hat{p} - (\hat{r} \cdot \hat{p})^2$ using Einstein Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, einstein-notation

**Problem**

> Show that $\hat{L}^2=\hat{r}^2\hat{p}^2 + i\hbar \hat{r} \cdot \hat{p} - (\hat{r} \cdot \hat{p})^2 $ using Einstein notation and commutation relations in QM.

**Attempt**

We know that $\hat{L}_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \hat{x}_j\hat{p}_k$ as the definition of orbital angular momentum. We also know that $\hat{L}^2 = \hat{L}_i\hat{L}_i$. Therefore, we have
$$
\hat{L}_i\hat{L}_i = \epsilon_{ijk} \hat{x}_j\hat{p}_k\,\epsilon_{ilm} \hat{x}_l\hat{p}_m = \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm} \hat{x}_j\hat{p}_k\hat{x}_l\hat{p}_m
$$
Using the fact that $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm} = \delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}$ gives us
$$
\hat{L}_i\hat{L}_i = \delta_{jl}\delta_{km} \hat{x}_j\hat{p}_k\hat{x}_l \hat{p}_m - \delta_{jm}\delta_{kl} \hat{x}_j\hat{p}_k\hat{x}_l \hat{p}_m
\\ = \hat{x}_l\hat{p}_m\hat{x}_l\hat{p}_m - \hat{x}_j \hat{p}_k \hat{x}_k \hat{p}_j
$$
We now make use of the Heisenberg uncertainty relationship
$$
[\hat{x}_l,\hat{p}_m] = \hat{x}_l\hat{p}_m-\hat{p}_m\hat{x}_l = i\hbar \delta_{lm} \Leftrightarrow \hat{x}_l\hat{p}_m = i\hbar \delta_{lm} + \hat{p}_m\hat{x}_l
$$
which therefore gives us
$$
\hat{L}_i\hat{L}_i = (i\hbar \delta_{lm} + \hat{p}_m\hat{x}_l) \hat{x}_l\hat{p}_m - \hat{x}_j\hat{p}_k\hat{x}_k\hat{p}_j = i\hbar \hat{x}_l\hat{p}_l + \hat{p}_m\ hat{x}_l \hat{x}_l\hat{p}_m - \hat{x}_j \hat{p}_k\hat{x}_k\hat{p}_j
$$
where $\hat{x}_l\hat{p}_l = \hat{r} \cdot \hat{p}$ as $\hat{r} = \hat{x}_i$.

All that is left to show is that $$\hat{p}_m\hat{x}_l\hat{x}_l\hat{p}_m - \hat{x}_j \hat{p}_k\hat{x}_k\hat{p}_j = \hat{r}^2\hat{p}^2 - (\hat{r} \cdot \hat{p})^2
$$
but here's where I'm struggling and don't know how to move forward. I can't really see how to manipulate those expression to get what I want. I'd be glad if anyone could propose any ideas or tips on how to continue solving this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is already what you want. The first (respectively second) term on the left is the first (respectively second) term on the right. You can see this by grouping terms with the same index.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Oh of course! I suppose the rearrangment is justified since p and x commute along different axis, thanks.

Comment: There are $-2i\hbar \hat r \cdot \hat p$ terms in the rearrangement of the first and second terms, of course, cancelling each other, as they should!